# How to have a dynamic total_rows for Pagination CI?

Tags: php, pagination, codeigniter-3

My team and I have project wherein the view must have a functioning search box and a drop down menu to filter the results. All is functioning well, fortunately. But the problem is, the pagination total_rows is currently dependent on the search count only: `$config["total_rows"] = $this->Users_model->search_count($search);`

I have multiple functions that counts the results for the queries that are being used. How do I make the total_rows dynamic on the number of rows that are showing up?

Here is my config:

```
 public function viewborrower() {
    $data['title'] = 'View Borrowers';

    $configAllBorrowers = array();

    $search = $this->input->get("borrow_name"); //input form to search
    $field  = $this->input->get('loantype'); //input form to filter

    $configAllBorrowers["base_url"] = base_url() . "/index.php/Users/viewborrower";
    $configAllBorrowers["total_rows"] = $this->Users_model->get_view_borrowers_search_count($search);
    $configAllBorrowers["per_page"] = 8;
    $configAllBorrowers["uri_segment"] = 3;

    if (count($_GET) > 0) $configAllBorrowers['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET);
    $configAllBorrowers['first_url'] = $configAllBorrowers['base_url'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET);
    
    $configAllBorrowers['cur_page'] = $this->uri->segment(3) ?: -1;
    $configAllBorrowers['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';        
    $configAllBorrowers['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';        
    $configAllBorrowers['first_link'] = 'First';        
    $configAllBorrowers['last_link'] = 'Last';        
    $configAllBorrowers['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configAllBorrowers['first_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configAllBorrowers['prev_link'] = '&laquo';        
    $configAllBorrowers['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configAllBorrowers['prev_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configAllBorrowers['next_link'] = '&raquo';        
    $configAllBorrowers['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configAllBorrowers['next_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configAllBorrowers['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configAllBorrowers['last_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';        
    $configAllBorrowers['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';        
    $configAllBorrowers['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';        
    $configAllBorrowers['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">';        
    $configAllBorrowers['num_tag_close'] = '</span></li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($configAllBorrowers);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    if (!empty($search) && !empty($field)) {//if both search and filter has a value
        $configAllBorrowers["total_rows"] = $this->Users_model->get_borrowers_by_name_loantype_count($field, $search);
        $data['borrowerlist'] = $this->Users_model->get_borrowers_by_name_loantype($configAllBorrowers['per_page'], $page, $field, $search);
        $data['searchborrowercount'] = $this->Users_model->get_borrowers_by_name_loantype_count($field, $search);
    } elseif(!empty($field)) {//if filter only has a value
        $configAllBorrowers["total_rows"] = $this->Users_model->get_borrowers_by_loantype_count($field);
        $data['borrowerlist'] = $this->Users_model->get_borrowers_by_loantype($configAllBorrowers['per_page'], $page, $field);
        $data['searchborrowercount'] = $this->Users_model->get_borrowers_by_loantype_count($field);
    }else { //if search only has a value
        $configAllBorrowers["total_rows"] = $this->Users_model->get_view_borrowers_search_count($search);
        $data['borrowerlist'] = $this->Users_model->get_view_borrowers_search($configAllBorrowers['per_page'], $page, $search);
        $data['searchborrowercount'] = $this->Users_model->get_view_borrowers_search_count($search);
    }

    $data['borrowerlinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    
    $this->load->view('include/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/sidetopbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('user/viewborrower');
}
```

Here are the model functions that are being used

> function get_view_borrowers_search($limit, $start, $st)
> {

```
    $sql = "select * from $this->tbl_loan_application where col_borrower_id like '%$st%' or col_full_name like '%$st%' order by loan_id DESC limit " . $start . ", " . $limit;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

function get_view_borrowers_search_count($st = NULL)
{
    if ($st == "NULL") $st = "";
    $sql = "select * from $this->tbl_loan_application where col_borrower_id like '%$st%' or col_full_name like '%$st%'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->num_rows();
}

public function get_borrowers_by_name_loantype($limit, $start, $field, $search)
{
    $sql = "select * from $this->tbl_loan_application WHERE col_full_name LIKE '%$search%' and col_loan_type='$field' order by loan_id DESC limit " . $start . ", " . $limit;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

public function get_borrowers_by_name_loantype_count( $field, $search, $st = NULL)
{
    if ($st == "NULL") $st = "";
    $sql = "select * from $this->tbl_loan_application WHERE col_full_name LIKE '%$search%' and col_loan_type='$field'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->num_rows();

}

public function get_borrowers_by_loantype($limit, $start, $field)
{
    $sql = "select * from $this->tbl_loan_application WHERE col_loan_type='$field' ORDER BY loan_id desc limit " . $start . ", " . $limit;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}

public function get_borrowers_by_loantype_count($field, $st = NULL)
{
    if ($st == "NULL") $st = "";
    $sql = "select * from $this->tbl_loan_application WHERE col_loan_type='$field'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

I have multiple functions that counts the results for the queries that are being used. How do I make the total_rows dynamic on the number of rows that are showing up?

Comment: Shouldn't you set `$configAllBorrowers["total_rows"]` before  `$this->pagination->initialize($configAllBorrowers);`

Comment: Is that how it should be? So i should add the $page line first, then the conditions, then the pagination initialization?

Comment: Yes moving the line `$this->pagination->initialize($configAllBorrowers);` after the if/else 
 group should do the trick.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).